# How do I fix "The term 'sh' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program." while installing k3s?

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes, sh, k3s

I am new to kubernetes and docker. I have been trying to install k3s on my Windows 10 system with the command mentioned on the website:

```
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -
```

I already have `minikube`, `kubectl` and `docker` installed on my system, and all work as expected.
However, when I run the above command, I get the following error message:

```
sh : The term 'sh' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:32
+ curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -
+                                ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sh:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: according to your tags you are running on windows. sh stands for shell. sh and bash (borne again shell) are used on linux and not available on windows by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time being **k3s** doesn't support **Windows**, but there is an [open issue](https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/issues/114) on **Github** you can track.

The [installation script](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/quick-start/#install-script) you are trying to run, simply won't work on **Windows** machine. If you take a closer look at the [installation requirements section](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/installation-requirements/) in the very same documentation, you will see the following information, regarding to the [supported Operating Systems](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/installation-requirements/#operating-systems):

> ### Operating Systems
>
> K3s is expected to work on most modern Linux systems.
>
> Some OSs have specific requirements:
>
> - If you are using  **Raspbian Buster**, follow  [these steps](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/advanced/#enabling-legacy-iptables-on-raspbian-buster)
>   to switch to legacy iptables.
> - If you are using  **Alpine Linux**, follow  [these steps](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/advanced/#additional-preparation-for-alpine-linux-setup)
>   for additional setup.
> - If you are using  **(Red Hat/CentOS) Enterprise Linux**, follow  [these
>   steps](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/advanced/#additional-preparation-for-red-hat-centos-enterprise-linux)
>   for additional setup.
>
> For more information on which OSs were tested with Rancher managed K3s
> clusters, refer to the  [Rancher support and maintenance
> terms.](https://rancher.com/support-maintenance-terms/)

So for running **k3s** on **Windows** you would need a **Linux VM** which can be provisioned using a hypervisor like **Hyper-V** or **VirtualBox** that can be run on your **Windows host**.

Take a look at the following article that presents how it can be done by using **Hyper-V**:

[Rancher 2.4 & Kubernetes on your Windows 10 laptop with multipass & k3s — Elasticsearch/Kibana in minutes!](https://jyeee.medium.com/rancher-2-4-14c31af12b7a)

Comment: Thank you so much! Helped me understand really well.